# What method to call to update my overlay view in google map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've defined an overlay (implementing OverlayView) and after defining my overlay, I need to update some content in overlay. But it doesn't take effect unless I move the map.

What method to call so my overlay updates without moving the map? Is there a update/render method to update the view?

Comment: Link to live code would be very valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using setMap(null) for removing the overlay and then redraw the complete overlay.

Answer (score 8):

You can call the `draw()` function on the OverlayView, see the [reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#OverlayView) for more info.